# Compiling C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to c++. I am also new to Visual Studio.
When I compile this code it says it succeeded, but it doesn't let me enter the number so that the function will run. I am not sure if I am  writing the code wrong or just not understanding the compiling capabilities of Visual Studio. I'm use to java and NetBeans by the way.

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int no; // int named no.
    std::cout << "Enter any number: ";
    std::cin>>no;
    if (no % 2 == 0) {
        std::cout << "Even number,";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "odd Number";
    }


}
```

Comment: Not sure what's getting you here. If you type in a number and the program window instantly closes, unfortunately that's the expected behaviour. When the program ends, the window goes away. [Place a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017) on the final } to force the program to stop and let you see the result.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: what kind of project type have u created?

Comment: Try adding `System.pause();` to the end of program if you can see a command window disappearing once. Or use a console application type.

Comment: @Gimhani there is no such thing as `System.pause()` in C++. Also, Visual Studio 2017 keeps console applications open by itself.

Comment: VS keeps the console open now? That's good new assuming it's implemented well. Suck to see "Why can't I compile? (Because VS is holding your program open and unwritable)" questions replace "Where'd my console go?"

Comment: user4581301 It doesn't open a window, it doesn't allow for any keyboard input. It just runs the code then declares it a success.

Comment: @Gimhani I created it under console application. I am not exactly sure how I wound up with this type, but I couldn't find a win32 specifically. Also a command window does not open at all.

Comment: Have you... actually RUN the program or just COMPILED it? (F5 key in Visual Studio to run the program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow so it won't let me write a comment but I think I know your problem. I think you might be compiling but not actually running your code. Try hitting Ctrl + F5 or go up to the 'Debug' tab and click 'Start without Debugging'.